# Daily Transaction Data on Solana Network

Tags: transactions, historical-data

I am not certain if this is the right forum to post this question but I am looking for historical **daily transaction data for the Solana network**. I searched around various explorers and sites but none provide this data for download.

Does anyone know of any site or resource where I can find this data? Or point me in the direction of where I could derive/request this data?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Is something like this helpful for you? I don't know about downloading, though.

https://chaincrunch.cc/dashboards.html

Comment: Thank you @HelmetFace but yes I am looking for downloadable data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all transactions, you can use the JSON RPC `getBlock` API which returns the block and all transactions included in a slot.  For example, you can do:

```
curl http://localhost:8899 -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {"jsonrpc": "2.0","id":1,"method":"getBlock","params":[430, {"encoding": "json","transactionDetails":"full","rewards":false}]}
'
```

Then you can iterate through all slots and call `getBlock` on each one.

More information at https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getblock